# puppet run ruby script with execute shell command and variable not working.

Tags: ruby, shell, puppet

my code

```
cmd_result = %x("#{rndc}" "#{cmd_arg}" "#{zone}" in "#{view}")

puts "#{$?.exitstatus}"
puts cmd_result
```

does not return any output and the exit status is 1. when run with puppet.

but if I ran it manually it works normally.

Comment: Did you try printing what those variables expand to when called from inside puppet class?

Comment: How is this being used inside Puppet?

Comment: @codeforester I add this to my code.
cmd = "#{rndc} #{cmd_arg} #{zone} in #{view}"
logger.debug("cmd: #{cmd}")
#run the command
cmd_result = eval "%x(#{cmd})"
logger.debug("Node_Name=#{hostname} View=#{view} Zone=#{zone} api_link= #{api_link} Auth_token=#{auth_token} rndc=[#{cmd_result}]")

Comment: The result in log is 
D, [2016-12-29T12:52:13.851190 #28224] DEBUG -- : cmd: /home/system/bind/sbin/rndc zonestatus tikusxxyz.my in internal
D, [2016-12-29T12:52:13.854864 #28224] DEBUG -- : cmd_result: 
D, [2016-12-29T12:52:13.904924 #28224] DEBUG -- : Node_Name=dnsvnode1 View=internal Zone=tikusxxyz.my api_link= http://dnsvplatform:3030/api/v1/nodes/dns/views/zones/update_status Auth_token=Token iCDDAftiii2hzpnQMCrK2gtt rndc=[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are (I think) trying to run ruby code from Puppet.

Puppet uses a DSL *written* in ruby. I suggest you get started [here](https://learn.puppet.com/)

Comment: but I can excute external command right? I mean if I want to run a bash or even python it would be no problem with exec resource type right?